# Big 2 Game Control ( Controls Flow of Game)

Tags: c++

I am creating a game Big 2 game in C++ , I have created a deck of 52 cards , Four Hand objects , A dealer object that will shuffle and deal these cards to the hand objects. This part is completed. Now, The player that has a diamond of 3 will start the game at the beginning. Then it will be the turn of player 2 , player 3 , player 4. But if Player 2 has it then it will be Player 2 who will begin the game and player 3's turn and player 4 and player 1.

There are many possibilities as after each round a new player will be the winner . I cannot find a way to make loop and reuse the codes again till the number of cards in the hand is 0 which is the condition for the player to win. It is very hard to control this flow for four players , If it was for 2 players it would be easy but 4 players means many conditions those players are of object type. 
Please Suggest me some ideas to implement game flow of Big 2 because if we complete this part we will be able to complete the game!

Note : The player's current play is matched with the previous player's played card!

Comment: "Please don't declare the question as not clear because I really need an answer". This question is not clear at all. You should probably post some code specific to the issues that you are having. In addition, never tell the people you are seeking help from "not to do" something.

Comment: Modulo arithmetic:  `next_player_index = (next_player_index + 1) % TOTAL_PLAYERS;` Or to go the other direction:  `next_player_index = (next_player_index + TOTAL_PLAYERS - 1) % TOTAL_PLAYERS;`.

Comment: Ternary operator: `next_player_index = next_player_index + 1 > TOTAL_PLAYERS - 1? 0 : next_player_index + 1;` Or go the other direction: `next_player_index = next_player_index - 1 < 0 ? TOTAL_PLAYERS - 1 : next_player_index + 1;` sorry I had too just for fun!

Answer (score 2):

Forgive me if I am wrong but you are asking how to track the order of player per round right?

If this is the case it sounds like you should store you Player objects in an array in counter-clockwise order. Now you only need to track last player as an index the next player should be the next index. I assume that you have your cards stored as integers and in the order of lowest to highest but that is another guess. According to the rules that would be diamonds, hearts, clubs, spades with diamonds being the lowest. For each suit 3 is the lowest and 2 is the highest everything int the middle sounds standard "3, 4, 5, ... J, Q, K, A, 2".

```
void startRound(void)
{
    // six cards created during deal
    if(kitty.hasThree())
    {
        int lowestCard = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            int playerLowestCard = players[i].getLowestCard();
            if(playerLowestCard < lowestCard)
            {
                startPlayer = i;
                lowestCard = playerLowestCard;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if(players[i].hasThree())
            {
                startPlayer = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think I understand you question and the game of [Big Deuce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Two) well enough.

**EDIT:** if you are wondering how to loop for the next player that would be...

```
void goToNextPlayer(void) {
    startPlayer++;
    if(startPlayer >= 4) {
        startPlayer = 0;
    }
}
```

I don't know why I am calling that index `startPlayer` it should be `playerIndex` or something.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but doing the way you have told me will allow me to implement the players after the current player. Example if player 2 wins then player 3 and player 4 , in conditions of array but what about player 1 ? If we do it like this i think there will be so many conditions as well and might not solve the problem because the input given by player 2 needs to be stored in an array and compared to the previous one and so on.

Comment: I don't understand the issue player 1's index = 0. and you start at 0 if you are greater than 3 you go back to 0. Also if you need to change the starting player you use the code above to find the player who would start the round. Technically the game should have 5 hands and 4 players. One hand for each player and the hand on the table the hand on the table can be from 1 to 5 cards while the hand each player has can be form 11 to 17 _"depending on the rules your using"_. The winner is the first person to get rid of all there cards right? Then it starts over again.